# Creating a random value in the dictionary while looping over a list and appending

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, random, jupyter-notebook

I need to create a dictionary structure in the below format.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

list_3 = random.sample(list_2 , random.randint(0,len(list_2))
```

Loop as the len(list_1) and need to loop using list_2 and then using the random sample created using list_3, assigning each value of the list_3 as a value in the inner dictionary below, while iterating.

*Needed dictionary format:

```
my_dict = { 1: { 1: a, 
                 2:b, 
                 3,c},
             2: { 1: 'd',
                  2: 'g'},
             3: {1, 'e',
                 2, 'f',
                 3, 'g'}
                .....
               }*
```

My code:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

list_4= []

j= 1

while i <= len(list_1):

    list_3 = random.sample(list_2 , random.randint(0,len(list_2))

    for k in list_3:

        my_dict= { i: { j: k, 
                      }
                 }

        j+=1

    i+=1

    list_3 = random.sample(list_2 , random.randint(0,len(list_2))
    list_4.append(my_dict)
```

The jth value should increment after every iterating of list_3 and keep adding a new jth key + value (k)
After the loop ends of list_3, another sample list (list_3) should be created and the above same repeats in the new ith key and gets added to the dictionary.

I am not getting the required result and need help if anyone can fix the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `my_dict` in every iteration of the loop. You only need to add a new subdict with key `i`:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
my_dict = {}
for i in list_1:
    list_3 = random.sample(list_2 , random.randint(0,len(list_2)))
    my_dict[i] = dict(enumerate(list_3, 1))
```

Comment: This helped. But i am stuck at one more place while creating this dictionary  - my_dict[i] = dict(enumerate(list_3, 1)), i need to add another key (string) 
 and value(random integer) pair which needs to be added simultaneously to dictionary my_dict[i] . How can i do it?

Comment: You can do it after this last line using `my_dict[i][my_key] = my_value` …

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a list of `keys` and a list of `values` and you want to create a dictionary with one entry for each `key`, where the value for each `key` is a dictionary with a random selection from `values` as values and sequential numerical keys, starting at 1.

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

result = {
    k: {n: v 
        for n, v in enumerate(random.sample(values, random.randint(0, len(values))), 1)
    } 
    for k in keys }
```

This:

- defines a dictionary;

  `result= {}`
- with an entry for each key `k` in `keys`;

  `result= {k: {} for k in keys}`
- with each dictionary having keys and values from an enumeration starting at 1;

  `{n: v for n, v in enumerate([], 1)}`
- with the values being a random sample from `values`;

  `random.sample(values, _)`
- with a length between 0 and all items in `values`.

  `random.sample(random.randint(0, len(values)))`

And Python allows you to just turn the enumeration into a dict directly:

```
result = {
    k: dict(enumerate(random.sample(values, random.randint(0, len(values))), 1))
    for k in keys }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
    import random
    list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    for i in list_1:
        list_3 = random.sample(list_2 , random.randint(0,len(list_2)))
        my_dict[i]=dict(enumerate(list_3,1))
    print(my_dict)
```